# iPad won't accept Verizon SIM

Tags: ipad, sim

I have an iPad 4 model #1459(wifi/cellular) tied into AT&T/T-Mobile
 my carrier is Verizon. Is there anyway to change my ipad to Verizon?
I dropped in a Verizon sim card but got an error message "Sim is not Valid". It states insert SIM card from a supported carrier or request that this iPad be unlocked by your carrier and to contact Apple for more info.

Comment: No iPad is carrier locked. What happens if you remove the SIM card and connect it to iTunes? Also, please edit in the version of OS on the iPad - it might just need an update to a more recent version of iOS. Lastly - ask us a specific question. Tell us what you want the end result to be - even if you don't know how to get there. Cheers and Welcome to Ask Different.

Answer (score 1):

Why not work through this checklist from Apple before contacting either the Carrier support or Apple Support?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201415

Since you have a specific error message, you might also jump to one of the last steps first. Back up the iPad and restore it to factory new settings and re-test the SIM card that you think should be active.

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201252

I've needed to call Verizon to get a SIM card to be part of a shared pool of data, but any active Verizon SIM should work, so once you rule out the iOS software - re-verify that the SIM you have is truly active.

Answer (score -1):

Try a settings reset  or set your carrier to custom  it may be a locked or un activated sim card.